# Integration regarding joint probability density functions to find required expectations

Tags: integration, solution-verification, expected-value, conditional-expectation, density-function

**Question**

Suppose that random variables $X$ and $Y$ have joint probability density function (PDF) $$f_{X, Y}(x, y) = e^{-x},\quad 0 < y < x.$$

Find $\mathbb{E}(Ye^{-X})$ and $\mathbb{E}(Ye^{-X}\ |\ Y = 2)$.

---

**My working**

$$\mathbb{E}(Ye^{-X}) = \int^{\infty}_y \int^x_0 ye^{-x}f_{X, Y}(x, y)\ \mathrm{d}y\ \mathrm{d}x$$

$$\mathbb{E}(Ye^{-X}\ |\ Y = 2) = \int^{\infty}_0 2e^{-x}f_{X|2}(x|2)\ \mathrm{d}x$$

---

I have just covered (conditional) expectations for joint random variables and would like to know if my methods for calculating them are correct. In particular, are my limits of integration for the respective integrals right? If not, please do tell where I have gone wrong :)

Comment: The lower limit of $x$ in the first integral should be $0$. Also the lower limit for the second integral should be $2$.

Comment: @MathLover Hello. You found me again. Haha. For the first integral, I thought the relevant support is $0 < y < x$, so $x > y$? Why do we use $0$ and not $y$ for the lower limit of $x$? I do understand the rationale for the lower limit of the second integral though.

Comment: yes I did find you :) Yes that is correct $x \geq y$ or $y \leq x$ and that is covered in limits of $y$. Limits of $x$ has to be $0$ to $\infty$.

Comment: @MathLover I am still confused for the first integral. I know in general $0 < x < \infty$, but since $x > y$ and $y > 0$, then shouldn't the "new" lower bound of $x$ be $y$? In fact, isn't this how we determine the lower bound of $x$ for the second integral? We know that $y = 2$, so from the support, $0 < 2 < x$ and thus $x > 2$? I am just applying the same logic to the first integral.

Comment: Though it is not an explanation but first thing to note is that if you keep limits of $x$, which is outer integral, in terms of $y$ then your final result is in terms of $y$. That is not what you would want. Anyway coming back to explanation. There is a difference with the first integral. The first integral is a double integral. Say you have a triangle with coordinates of vertices as $(0, 0), (2, 0)$ and $(2, 2)$. In other words it is bound by lines $y = 0, x = 2, y = x$. How do you find its area? It cannot be $\int_y^2 \int_0^x dy \ dx$, right?

Comment: It is rather $\int_0^2 \int_0^x dy \ dx$. The way to read it is that $x$ varies from $0$ to $2$ and for any value of $x$, $y$ varies between $0$ and $x$. Same thing here in your question. $x$ varies from $0$ to $\infty$ and for any value of $x$, $y$ varies from $0$ to $x$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123213/discussion-between-math-lover-and-ethan-mark).

Comment: You cannot apply the same logic, @EthanMark  The variable of integration for the inner integral is bound to it, and cannot occur outside its scope - thus its domain is restricted by the variable for the outer integral, but it cannot restrict the domain of the outer integral.    $$\begin{align}\iint_{a<y<x<b} g(x,y)\mathrm d \langle x,y\rangle &=\int_{a<x<b}\int_{a<y<x} g(x,y)\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x\\&=\int_{a<y<b}\int_{y<x<b}g(x,y)\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d y\end{align}$$  [when the conditions for Fubini's theorem hold.]

Comment: @GrahamKemp Yes. I understand that now. Thank you for the extra explanation :)